# How to make variable be still defined after EventListener in reactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, variables, scope, global-variables

I have problem with variable "icons" in my code. Its initialized and defined in EventListener scope but it is not defined after that scope so I got an error when I try to compile. I really don't know how to make global variable in reactJS and after searching for it looks like its not recommended to do so. So is there a way to make that variable work outside EventListener scope so class "Demo" could use it?

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.png';
import './App.css';
import Skycons from 'react-skycons';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">

        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />

        <div class="location"> 
    <h1 class="location-timezone"> Lokalizacja </h1>
    <Demo />    
</div>

<div class="temperature">
    <div class="degree-section">

    <h2 class="temperature-degree"> Brak </h2>
        <span> °C </span>
    </div>
    <div class="temperature-description"> Brak </div>

</div>

<div class="sekcja-jutro">
    <h1>Pogoda na Jutro: </h1>
</div>

<div class="minimalna">
    <span>Minimalna:</span>
    <h1 class="temperatura-minimalna"> Brak </h1>
    <span> °C </span> 
</div>

<div class="maksymalna">
    <span>Maksymalna:</span>
    <h1 class="temperatura-maksymalna"> Brak </h1>
    <span>°C</span>
</div>

    </div>


  );
}

window.addEventListener('load',()=> {
    let long;
    let lat;
    let temperatureDescription = document.querySelector(".temperature-description");
    let temperatureDegree = document.querySelector(".temperature-degree");
    let locationTimezone = document.querySelector(".location-timezone");
    let minimalna = document.querySelector(".temperatura-minimalna");
    let maksymalna = document.querySelector(".temperatura-maksymalna");

    if(navigator.geolocation){
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position =>{
                long = position.coords.longitude;
                lat = position.coords.latitude;

                const proxy = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
                const api = `${proxy}https://api.darksky.net/forecast/1539bbb708779eef3993021296196cb2/${lat},${long}`;

                fetch(api)
            .then(response =>{
                return response.json(); 
            })
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                const {temperature, summary, icon} = data.currently;

                var icons;  //there is initialized
                icons = icon.replace(/-/g, "_").toUpperCase();  //there is defined
                console.log(icons); //There I make it display in console so I see that it works as it should

                temperatureDegree.textContent = temperature;
                let celcjusz = (temperature - 32) * 5/9;
                temperatureDegree.textContent = Math.floor(celcjusz);
                temperatureDescription.textContent = summary;
                locationTimezone.textContent = data.timezone;

                const {temperatureLow} = data.daily.data[1];
                minimalna.textContent = temperatureLow;          
                let celcjusz1 = (temperatureLow - 32) * 5/9;
                minimalna.textContent = Math.floor(celcjusz1);

                const {temperatureMax} = data.daily.data[1];
                maksymalna.textContent = temperatureMax;          
                let celcjusz2 = (temperatureMax - 32) * 5/9;
                maksymalna.textContent = Math.floor(celcjusz2);
            });
            });
        }
    });
      class Demo extends React.Component {
        render () {
          return (
            <Skycons 
              class="icon"  
              color='white' 
              icon={icons}  //There I make display icon as anything is in "icons" variable but after compiling I got error that icons is not defined
              autoplay={true}
              height="130"                 
            />
          )
        }
      }
export default App;
```

Comment: I think react [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) may be able to help. Attach the listener and set the context value in the Provider to the computed icons value, then use the Consumer (or useContext hook) where you need that value.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html
Read this, think about state and props. Use state in the child, let the callback change state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow!

As you found out you should not create global variables. (In general they are not a good idea)

You are using a functional component `function App()` which man you can use [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)

You can use the `useEffect` hook to replace `window.onload` and `useState` to have internal state for the component.

Something like this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import logo from './logo.png';
import './App.css';
import Skycons from 'react-skycons';    
function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    long: null,
    lat: null,
    temperatureDescription: "",
    temperatureDegree: 0,
    locationTimezone: "",
    minimalna: 0,
    maksymalna: 0,
    icons: ""
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
        // save lat/long to save in state and later use
        const lat = position.coords.latitude;
        const long = position.coords.longitude;
        setState({
          ...state,
          lat,
          long
        });

        const proxy = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
        const api = `${proxy}https://api.darksky.net/forecast/1539bbb708779eef3993021296196cb2/${lat},${long}`; // <-- use lat/long

        fetch(api)
          .then(response => {
            return response.json();
          })
          .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            const { temperature, summary, icon } = data.currently;

            const celcjusz = ((temperature - 32) * 5) / 9;

            const { temperatureLow } = data.daily.data[1];
            const celcjusz1 = ((temperatureLow - 32) * 5) / 9;

            const { temperatureMax } = data.daily.data[1];
            const celcjusz2 = ((temperatureMax - 32) * 5) / 9;
            setState({
              ...state,
              temperatureDescription: summary,
              temperatureDegree: Math.floor(celcjusz),
              locationTimezone: data.timezone,
              minimalna: Math.floor(celcjusz1),
              maksymalna: Math.floor(celcjusz2),
              icons: icon.replace(/-/g, "_").toUpperCase() //there is defined
            });
          });
      });
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />

      <div class="location">
        <h1 class="location-timezone"> Lokalizacja </h1>
        <Demo icons={state.icons} />
      </div>

      <div class="temperature">
        <div class="degree-section">
          <h2 class="temperature-degree"> Brak </h2>
          <span> {state.temperatureDegree}°C </span>
        </div>
        <div class="temperature-description">
          {" "}
          {state.temperatureDescription}{" "}
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="sekcja-jutro">
        <h1>Pogoda na Jutro: </h1>
      </div>

      <div class="minimalna">
        <span>Minimalna:</span>
        <h1 class="temperatura-minimalna"> Brak </h1>
        <span> {state.minimalna}°C </span>
      </div>

      <div class="maksymalna">
        <span>Maksymalna:</span>
        <h1 class="temperatura-maksymalna"> Brak </h1>
        <span>{state.maksymalna}°C</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

class Demo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Skycons
        class="icon"
        color="white"
        icon={this.props.icons} //There I make display icon as anything is in "icons" variable but after compiling I got error that icons is not defined
        autoplay={true}
        height="130"
      />
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

I did not test it if it runs but in theory this should be your goal. Please not `useEffect` runs after render. This means if you want you can show a loading animation or text until `long!=null` for better user experience.

Comment: Thanks for help :) I tried ur code so at line 27 where is that link to connect to API at the end of the link there are "${lat}" and "{$long}" variables undefined, guess that I should change them to "${state.lat},${state.long}". Now they are defined but always as null so I can't connect to API because somehow navigator.geolocation now isn't working with those variables and they are always as they were first initialized which is null value. Im pretty new at javascript. Im more exprienced with C++ and C# so this is kind of new thing for me.

Comment: You should use `position.coords.latitude` (and `longitude`) as that is what is in scope, or you can save them as lat/long *before* `setState` and use in both places.

Comment: @DrewReese is correct. I forgot to deal with that API URL. Thanks for the edit!

Comment: Thank you guys very much :) Now everything works as It should.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are using the 'load' event correctly, I think that you can put you listener in a DidMount or useEffect in the App, and use the state of the app, passing to the component Demo as Parameters: